# Facebook SDK login with existing token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an android app with social network login support. And now I faced an issue that with logging in and out to the Facebook SDK. On our server we are storing the access token for every social network we use. What I want to do:

- user has an account with Google sign-in and Facebook account linked
- users logs out = he gets logged out from Facebook SDK and Google SDK
- users loggs in back with Google
- he receives the information about facebook token
- he is automatically logged in with Facebook

I have tried looking at the LoginManager class but couldn't find any ways to log in with access token.

I have also noticed that there is a way to set access token to AccessToken object. But I need some clarification on how to implement it correctly and on the logic behind that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant automatically connect Facebook SDK with tokens even app is already logged in. You need to ask user again to get a new access token.

On the other hand, facebook tokens that taken from mobile sdk are [short-term tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) unless replacing it the long-term token. Backend need to ask for [long-term one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension/) with the given one. So that, storing it might be unuseful.

Its better to feed your profile informations with data taken from Facebook and Google.

The way you found for setting access token is just for custom token refreshment structures.